# Ctrl-p Vim bug - unclear what error message is telling me

Tags: vim

```
 prt  path  <mru>={ files }=<buf> <->                                                                                        /home/.... 
Error detected while processing function <SNR>48_NormalPasta:
line   13:
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

kind of a strange vim error I get when I try to type the 'p' character using vim & ctrlp, using linux ubuntu here

Comment: Could you provide reproducible steps? It looks like simply typing 'p' in ctrlp prompt will not trigger the error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take that message one line at a time:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>48_NormalPasta:
```

There is an error in function `NormalPasta()` in the 48th script that was sourced by Vim.

```
line   13:
```

The error is on line 13 of that function.

```
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

The function is trying to edit a non-modifiable buffer.

From there, you can do:

```
:filter 48 scriptnames
```

or:

```
$ grep -R NormalPasta ~/.vim/**/*.vim
```

to find in what script the problematic function is located.

This leads to [this plugin](https://github.com/sickill/vim-pasta/blob/master/plugin/pasta.vim#L23), which appears to be OK. The whole situation seems rather strange, though, because the problematic function is supposed to be called from normal mode and I don't think a) that you should be in normal mode at CtrlP's prompt and b) that the CtrlP prompt is supposed to be non-modifiable.

My opinion is that the vim-pasta plugin is OK and thus that there is something fishy going on with CtrlP itself or *the way you use it*.

Comment: you can simply use `:scriptnames 48` to edit (or view) the problematic plugin

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I didn't know that, thanks, (`:help :scriptnames`). The intent is not to edit the script, though, only to identify it.

Comment: yes understood. But it usually helps to view/edit the script to identify it :)